# How do you get rid of data roaming pop up

Tags: roaming, data

I have a data roaming pop up every 5 mins on my S23 Ultra with T mobile service, I live Across Lake Erie From Canada, PLEASE!!! does anyone know how to get rid of it

Comment: Living next to borders is often a problem when it comes to cellular services and roaming. If supported by the phone you could try to change the network selection form automatic to manual and select your MNO's home network.

Comment: Doesn't work, and being Fire Chief in my area a can't just switch back and forth and forth anyway

Comment: So your MNO also uses roaming in your country (e.g. to allow you to use the cellular towers of a different provider)? Because otherwise you don't have to switch the network.